# OpenFileDialog always display the first file opened

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to use OpenFileDialog to open multiple files
and play them in a winforms media player COM component.
Everything seem to work, though in the listbox I see the first file name
times number of files selected.

```
_playList.Items.Clear();
string[] filenames = { };
_openFile.Multiselect = true;
_openFile.ShowDialog();
//filenames = _openFile.FileNames;
foreach (var name in _openFile.FileNames)
{
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_openFile.FileName);
    _playList.Items.Add(filename);                
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the error first pointed by [HABO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92546/habo), however I wish to give also this answer because a ListBox.Items has a method called AddRange that can be used with a single line of code using Linq

```
_playList.Items.AddRange(_openFile.FileNames
                                  .Select (fn => Path.GetFileName(fn))
                                  .ToArray());
```

Comment: one last thing. how can i make windowsmediaplayer play them in order? or even better bind the list as a mediaplayer playlist?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the workings of WMP, Perhaps if you post a new question specifying the problem well then you could get the attention of some guys expert with this

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `name` from your `foreach` loop:

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name);
```